# How to find out the cell names on range selection using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to find out the names of the cells user selected in excel sheet. Check out the below image for clarity. In the sample, i need to retrieve all the cell names (A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1) using VBA macro.

[image]

I am able to find out how many cells selected, But dont know how to retrieve their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking to store the names into an array, you'd need to loop through all the cells in the range, and store the address of each of the cells into an array or collection.  Here is a sample to get you started:

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    Dim addressArr() As String
    Dim i As Long

    addressArr = GetSelectedCells(Selection)

    For i = LBound(addressArr) To UBound(addressArr)
        MsgBox addressArr(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function GetSelectedCells(selectedRng As Range) As String()

    Dim cellArr() As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim cellArr(0 To (selectedRng.Cells.Count - 1))
    i = 0 'setup index for storing to array

    For Each cell In selectedRng

        cellArr(i) = cell.Address(False, False) 'modify the address here to get reference style

        i = i + 1
    Next cell

    GetSelectedCells = cellArr
End Function
```